# Find a complete sufficient statistic for Uniform$(\theta, \theta + 1)$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, uniform-distribution, order-statistics, sufficient-statistics

Let $X_1, \cdot\cdot \cdot, X_n$ be a random sample from $U(\theta, \theta + 1)$, $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$.

Find a complete and minimal sufficient statistic $Y$ for $\theta$.

I proved that $T(X) = (X_{(1)}, X_{(n)})$ is a minimal sufficient statistics for $\theta$. However, it can be shown that $T(X)$ is not complete.

Any hints to find a complete sufficient statistics?

Many thanks!

You can find this problem in https://www-math.umd.edu/images/pdfs/quals/Statistics/Statistics-PhD-August-2022.pdf

Comment: Don't think there is a complete sufficient statistic.

Comment: Part (b) of the same Problem 4 "Show that $Y$ is independent of sample range $R_n$" also looks strange

Comment: I think we can use Basu's Theorem for Part (b). We know that the sample range $R_n = X_{(n)} - X_{(1)}$ is location invariant and hence ancillary in this model. If we can find a complete sufficient statistic $Y$ then by the theorem it will be independent of sample range $R_n$.